# How to run mapply function row wise

Tags: r

I want row wise means of various datasets. I have heard that mapply handles performs iteration over multi data sets. Is it able to perform operations row wise. Like apply() do.

```
x<-matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=20)
y<-matrix(rnorm(500),nrow=20)
z<-matrix(rnorm(2000),nrow=30)
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] in your question!

Comment: see `?rowMeans()`

Comment: Maybe `lapply(list(x,y,z), rowMeans)`?